# ASP.NET MVC - jQuery document.ready() function not called

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I have a Razor view containing this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function()
    {
        alert("hello world");
    })
</script>
```

The script doesn't open an alert Dialog when the page is loaded.

Portion of the BundleCfg:

```
bundles.Add(New ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
            "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
            "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js",
            "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"))

bundles.Add(New ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
            "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"))
```

At the End of the Layout Body:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@RenderSection("scripts", required:=False)
```

Comment: there must be some problem with your registration of your bundle.

Comment: Could you specifiy the Problem please?

Comment: <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" ></script>
add this in your html file

Comment: You rely on the webservice with this Approach.

Comment: What about this `(function($) {
 $(document).ready(function() {
  // Code
 });
})(jQuery);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert("hello world");
});
```

here is details:
https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Acording to link on top I realized that your code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function()
    {
        alert("hello world");
    });
</script>
```

is the same as this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
      alert("hello world");
  });
</script>
```

So problem was just about place where to render bundles.

Comment: You should to declare 
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
before your JS.
I put it in <head> tag of layout

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the jQuery library is loaded after the symbol `$ (jQuery)` is called; that's why is doesn't work.

You have to put the line:

`@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")`

before the body is rendered.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code with this.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        alert("Hello World");
 });
```